# How to print progress every 10% using cURL download

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to capture the output of a curl download command in a python script using subprocess. The log should be flushed real-time in a specific state. It will run as an init container and another consumer will periodically check the progress.

With this said, the table and the progress bar are both quite unsuitable. I want the python script to print progress every 10 percent, on a new line.

Seems like curl doesn't natively support this kind of feature. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks.

### Desired behaviour:

(actually, ran with a python script, inside a docker image as a k8s init container)

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1/somefile
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

### Current behaviour 1: the line refreshes, it does not accumulate

```
$ curl --progress-bar http://127.0.0.1/somefile
##############                                                11.2%
```

### Current behaviour 2: the table refreshes

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1/somefile
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 97.6G    0 55.8M    0     0  17.0M      0  1:15:33  0:00:03  1:35:30 17.0M
```

Comment: I looked at a similar issue with `curl` and `bash` recently, and my summary was that `curl` writes errors AND the status information (the progress bar or other) to the `stderr` stream AND are using ansi escape codes to control the formatting (essentially discarding `\n` LF chars needed by typical shell based processes to parse "line-at-a-time" data.) Very difficult to filter the err msgs to pass thru as useful information. Run the linux `screen` utility (`man screen`), run one session from cmd-line and look at ` typescript` file. Maybe python allows other features using `curllib` . Good luck.

Comment: If I really wanted to do this, my solution would have been add a feature to curl allowing specify alternate streams for just the progress bar/status info. I mean like `5>&1` streams, but would have to passing that stream number as an option/arg to `curl`. Definitely interested if there is a hidden cmd in `curl` that isoliates the status info.

Comment: Thanks @shellter , looks like there is no such straightforward solution for this. I might just use third-party libraries, or try later with your suggestion. As curl is open-source, making such binary with the same capabilities won't be hard.

p.s. the reason I'm using curl is that it's faster than any other "modern" downloaders, even with multithread options and etc, under some specific internal environments.

Comment: Oh, yeah, and of course if you were going to modify the source, rather than mess with streams, you could just add the code to produce your desired format for status info.